# Aligning Dynamic Inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm trying to align dynamically created divs but I think I'm missing something fundamental.

I'm just trying to have a little space in between each input, but I don't understand how to target what is going to be the newly created element in the css.

Any help would be appreciated.  Essentially I am just trying to line them up beneath each other, but I'd like to be able to manipulate this to eventually mix with other css.

Link: http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/mArAGv

```
HTML:

<div id="fullName">
<p>Full Name</p>

<input type="text" name="firstName_1"  />

<input type="text" name="middleName_1" />   

    <input type="text" name="lastName_1" />

</div>

<input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="addName()" value="+" />

CSS:

*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

input
{
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#fullName
{
    margin-left: 30px;
}

JS:
var i = 0;

function addName()
{
    if(i <= 3)
    {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="firstName_'+i+'"><input type="text" name="middleName_'+i+'"><input type="text" name="lastName_'+i+'">';

        document.getElementById("fullName").appendChild(div);
    }
};
```

Comment: CSS doesn’t care if an element was there from the beginning, or dynamically added later. All you need is a criterion to select these elements by (f.e. a common class), and then write the matching selectors.

Comment: Would wrapping the div.innerHTML elements in a class of their own be the best method?

Comment: http://codepen.io/vikash2402/pen/vXJXqP will it work for u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just tried to handle using CSS.

```js
var i = 0;

function addName()
{
 if(i <= 3)
 {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="firstName_'+i+'"> <input type="text" name="middleName_'+i+'"> <input type="text" name="lastName_'+i+'">';
  
  document.getElementById("fullName").appendChild(div);
 }
};
```

```css
*
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.containerDiv{
 margin: 100px;
 
}

#fullName
{
 display:table;
}

p
{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 30px;
}

input
{
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#fullName
{
 margin-left: 30px;
}

/* .left
{
 margin-left: 99px;
} */
```

```html
<p>Full Name</p>
<div id="fullName" class:"containerDiv">

<input type="text" name="firstName_1"  />
 
<input type="text" name="middleName_1" /> 
 
 <input type="text" name="lastName_1" />
 
</div>

<input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="addName()" value="+" />
```

http://codepen.io/vikash2402/pen/JRybWZ

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: It's creating a new class but the class isn't aligning....Am I missing something? http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/rrzWZz

Comment: http://codepen.io/vikash2402/pen/JRybWZ try now.. changed a bit.. its working now?

Comment: Works perfectly! I see that you removed the class name of the div in favor of { } but how is the JS knowing to target the the class element?

Comment: As you can see I have added class to the static html element container(id = fullName)... well i have updated my answer accordingly.. please accept as an answer..